# Using react Slate/Plate to enforce first line char limit

Tags: reactjs, richtext, slate

I want to create a situation where the first line servers as title, limited to X chars. (say 70 characters) and the other lines could be any length.

For example :
**This is a title** 
Some other text goes here that explains the situation.

It should be similar to -
https://www.slatejs.org/examples/forced-layout in looks. Be the first line should enforce a limit. and after overflowing, it should move to the second line.

But every time I try to enforce some limit, I either enter an endless loop of checks or the cart jumps from one place to another. So apparently, I don't really know how to implement this behavior :)

I also haven't seen this behavior implemented on other sites, so I can't provide a concrete example.

I'd appreciate anything anyone can throw in my way to help me achieve this.

Comment: please put your tried code

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't any saved code for this issue. :(